# C# WPF XML Schema validation of abstract type

Tags: wpf, validation, xaml, serialization, schema

First of all I would like to say hallo everybody - it's my first post here on SO. Now important stuff. I am writing some code in C# WPF .NET 4.0 which is based on serialization / deserialization built-in mechanizms. Everything was fine untill I decided to create a validation schema for my serialized xml file. All of this would be more clear when I show a bit my code:

**Serialization**

```
private void serializeObjectsToFile(string path)
{
    using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path))
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(myTopClass.GetType());
        serializer.Serialize(writer, myTopClass);
        writer.Flush();
    }
}
```

**Deserialization**

```
private MyTopClass deserializeObjectsFromFile(string path)
{
    using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path))
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyTopClass));
        return serializer.Deserialize(stream) as MyTopClass;
    }
}
```

**Validation**

```
private bool validateXmlAgainstSchema(string pathToFile)
{
    XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
    schemas.Add("", schemaPath);

    XDocument inputFile = XDocument.Load(pathToFile);
    var isFileValid = true;
    inputFile.Validate(schemas, (o, e) =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Validation fails. {0}.", e.Message));
            isFileValid = false;
        });
    return isFileValid;
}
```

Now let me introduce my Model which is serialized to xml file and for which I want to create a validation schema.

**Top Class**

```
namespace SerializationVsSchemaTest.Model
{
    [Serializable]
    public class MyTopClass
    {
        public int myTopItemOne { get; set; }
        public int myTopItemTwo { get; set; }
        public int myTopItemThree { get; set; }
        public MyAbstractClass myTopAbstractItem { get; set; }

        public MyTopClass()
        {
            myTopItemOne = 7;
            myTopItemTwo = 8;
            myTopItemThree = 9;
            myTopAbstractItem = new ClassOne();
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{3}\n", myTopItemOne, myTopItemTwo, myTopItemThree, myTopAbstractItem.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

**Abstract Class - the most important stuff here and the root part of my question**

```
namespace SerializationVsSchemaTest.Model
{
    [XmlInclude(typeof(ClassOne))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(ClassTwo))]
    public abstract class MyAbstractClass
    {
    }
}
```

**ClassOne**

```
namespace SerializationVsSchemaTest.Model
{
    [Serializable]
    public class ClassOne : MyAbstractClass
    {
        public int argOne;
        public int argTwo;
        public int argThree;

        public ClassOne()
        {
            argOne = -1;
            argTwo = -2;
            argThree = -3;
        }
    }
}
```

**ClassTwo**

```
namespace SerializationVsSchemaTest.Model
{
    [Serializable]
    public class ClassTwo: MyAbstractClass
    {
        public byte argOne;
        public byte argTwo;
        public byte argThree;

        public ClassTwo()
        {
            argOne = 4;
            argTwo = 5;
            argThree = 6;
        }
    }
}
```

**Serialization result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyTopClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <myTopItemOne>7</myTopItemOne>
    <myTopItemTwo>8</myTopItemTwo>
    <myTopItemThree>9</myTopItemThree>
    <myTopAbstractItem xsi:type="ClassOne">
        <argOne>-1</argOne>
        <argTwo>-2</argTwo>
        <argThree>-3</argThree>
    </myTopAbstractItem>
</MyTopClass>
```

**My validation schema**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xsd:element name="MyTopClass">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="myTopItemOne" type="xsd:unsignedByte" />
            <xsd:element name="myTopItemTwo" type="xsd:unsignedByte" />
            <xsd:element name="myTopItemThree" type="xsd:unsignedByte" />
            <xsd:element name="myTopAbstractItem">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="argOne" type="xsd:byte" />
                        <xsd:element name="argTwo" type="xsd:byte" />
                        <xsd:element name="argThree" type="xsd:byte" />
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

And the problem here is that **this schema fails to validate my xml** with following result:
*Validation fails. Invalid type xsi:type 'ClassOne'.* The strangest thing is that this schema is generated by Visual Studio 2013 using my serialized xml file. So it should match 100%... I hope You guys will help me somehow. Cheers!